# What is the best practice to create an object and pass it to parent component?

Tags: reactjs

What is the best practice to create an object and pass it to parent component? My code below works well but it seems I have to throw in so much stuff here just to submit a simple form with 2 fields.

I'm creating constructor,

listening events,

binding events,

updating and passing state to App.js

Is this is the best practice?:

```
class AddFishForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      amount: ''
    };
    this.onTitleChange = this.onTitleChange.bind(this);
    this.onAmountChange = this.onAmountChange.bind(this);
  }
  onTitleChange = (e) => {
    const title = e.target.value;
    this.setState(() => ({ title }));
  };
  onAmountChange = (e) => {
    const amount = e.target.value;
    this.setState(() => ({ amount }));
  };

  createFish(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.addFish({
      url: this.state.url,
      title: this.state.title
    });
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <Segment>
        <Form onSubmit={(e) => this.createFish(e)}>
          <Form.Group >
            <Form.Input
              type='text'
              placeholder='picture url'
              autoFocus
              value={this.state.title}
              onChange={this.onTitleChange}
              width={6}
            />
            <Form.Input
              type='text'
              placeholder='title'
              autoFocus
              value={this.state.amount}
              onChange={this.onAmountChange}
              width={6}
            />
          </Form.Group >
          <Button fluid type='submit'>Submit</Button>
        </Form>
      </Segment>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your code by providing a more generic method which updates state:

```
onInputChange = (e) => {
  const target = e.target;
  const name = target.name;
  const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
  // add code for other input types
  this.setState(() => ({ [name]: value }));
};
```

bind this method in your constructor

```
this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
```

and use it on your elements

```
<input
  type='text'
  name='title'
  value={this.state.title}
  onChange={this.onInputChange}
  ...
/>

<input
  type='checkbox'
  name='is_subsribed'
  checked={this.state.is_subsribed}
  onChange={this.onInputChange}
  ...
/>
```

the name attribute will connect the input to the correct state value

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However I'm not 100% sure how to implement this in my code context. Could you provide the code which is more relevant to my case?

Comment: Thanks for updates, This works perfectly and way less code!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need further manipulation for `input`, use [uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). This is the uncontrolled-components version of your code

```
class AddFishForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  createFish(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const url = this._url.value;
    const title = this._title.value;
    this.props.addFish({ url, title });
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <Segment>
        <Form onSubmit={(e) => this.createFish(e)}>
          <Form.Group >            
            <input
              ref={input => this._url = input}
              type='text'
              width={6} />
            <input
              ref={input => this._title = input}
              type='text
              width={6} />
          </Form.Group >
          <Button fluid type='submit'>Submit</Button>
        </Form>
      </Segment>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man! but this was actually my initial implementation and I was getting this `Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.`

Comment: @karolis2017: My bad. Then you can still use a class components in order to access `ref`.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would start off something like this:

```
class AddFishForm extends React.Component {
  onInputChange() {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="semantic ui segment">
        <form className="ui form">
          <div className="field">
            <label>Image Search</label>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.onInputChange} />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddFishForm;
```

The `onInputChange()` will be ran with one argument being passed to it automatically, usually referred to as the `event` object. This object contains a bunch of information about the event that just occurred like so:

```
class AddFishForm extends React.Component {
  onInputChange(event) {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="semantic ui segment">
        <form className="ui form">
          <div className="field">
            <label>Image Search</label>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.onInputChange} />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddFishForm;
```

In the case of a user typing something, there is usually one property inside this entire object we care about and that is the `event.target.value` property. That will contain the text that the user just attempted to type into the input like so:

```
class AddFishForm extends React.Component {
  onInputChange(event) {
   event.target.value
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="semantic ui segment">
        <form className="ui form">
          <div className="field">
            <label>Image Search</label>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.onInputChange} />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddFishForm;
```

You can test this by console logging it out and seeing what you get like so:

```
class AddFishForm extends React.Component {
  onInputChange(event) {
   console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="semantic ui segment">
        <form className="ui form">
          <div className="field">
            <label>Image Search</label>
            <input type="text" onChange={this.onInputChange} />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddFishForm;
```

As you add text, it should be consoled out, that should be the expected behavior.

`onChange` is a very special property name. Different events are going to be wired to different property names. So in this case it looks like you want to be told anytime a user changes the text input so I am assuming thats why you are using the property name `onChange`.

For your event handlers, you are using community convention in your naming convention so you are good there.

So that is event handling in a nutshell. There is an alternate syntax for writing out event handlers.

```
class AddFishForm extends React.Component {
  onInputChange(event) {
   console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="semantic ui segment">
        <form className="ui form">
          <div className="field">
            <label>Image Search</label>
            <input type="text" onChange={(event) => console.log(event.target.value)} />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddFishForm;
```

This approach is good for when you don't have more than a single line of logic in your event handler method.

Now, in the example I offered inside the `render()` method, I have an **uncontrolled** form element. In general, as developers we want to work with controlled form elements. So I will refactor this so you can see the difference.

I bring this up because I saw that in your event handler you implemented `this.setState(() => ({ title }));`, but you want to be more deliberate with your implementation and if the idea is to have a controlled form element then you want to implement that like so:

```
class AddFishForm extends React.Component {
    state = {
      title: '',
      amount: ''
    };
  }

  createFish(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.addFish({
      url: this.state.url,
      title: this.state.title
    });
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <Segment>
        <Form onSubmit={(e) => this.createFish(e)}>
          <Form.Group >
            <Form.Input
              type='text'
              placeholder='picture url'
              autoFocus
              value={this.state.title}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ title: e.target.value })}
              width={6}
            />
            <Form.Input
              type='text'
              placeholder='title'
              autoFocus
              value={this.state.amount}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ amount: e.target.value })}
              width={6}
            />
          </Form.Group >
          <Button fluid type='submit'>Submit</Button>
        </Form>
      </Segment>
    )
  }
}
```

So you are updating the `title` and `amount` property with whatever the current value of the input is.

So why are we using `state`? Why are we updating state with `setState()` whenever we change the input and why are we passing something called `value`?

1. User types in input
2. Callback gets invoked, the `onChange`
3. Inside the callback we call `setState()` which updates our state to the new `value`. So `this.state.title` will contain what the user entered.
4. Component will re render itself.
5. We take `this.state.title` and assign it to the `value` prop of the input which will overwrite whatever text is already inside the input.

This can be proved by giving the value a string called  gibberish like so:

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  state = { term: '' };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="semantic ui segment">
        <form className="ui form">
          <div className="field">
            <label>Image Search</label>
            <input type="text" value="gibberish" onChange={(e) => this.setState({ term: e.target.value })} />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And when you go to your form in the browser, you will see gibberish already populated there.

So the five steps outlined above is the flow of a controlled element.